# Woocommerce product price update after cart quantity increase

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a product in my shop page after adding it to cart i want to change the quantity of that product. But the product price should be increased by 50% of the main product.
For example if product price is 100 and after increasing its quantity to 2 then product price should be 150. and on 3 it should be 200.
How can i change that in woo-commerce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many addon plugins which give you an feature to give quantity specific pricing in woocommerce. Some plugins like [woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-discounts](http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-discounts/7119279) and [woocommerce-dynamic-pricing](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing/) will help you to achieve the same.